# Why won't this jquery each() function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems like a straightforward bit of code to me but the console.log in the each() function simply isn't called:

```
    function updateLinks()
    {
        console.log("updateLinks() called");
        $("a .appended").each(function()
        {
            console.log("Checking for " + this.id + " in array");
            if($.inArray(this.id, savedTopics) > -1)
            {
                $(self).text("x");
            }
        });
    }
```

The first "updateLinks() called" message is displayed, but the each() function doesn't appear to run *at all*. None of the expected effects happen. The appended class is for a series of links I created earlier in the script. savedTopics is an array of integers returned from storage and is set just before this function is called. It all happens in the storage callback. Each of the links has a specific ID which is connected to the integers in storage.

What is preventing this code from running?

Comment: do you have another node with class appended? right now your selector says, `<a href=""><node class="appended"></node></a>`

Comment: Probably need to see some HTML

Comment: Kindly provide snippet of your HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to help you if you put up a JSFiddle, but maybe it's because what you really wanted to write is `$("a.appended")`, i.e. the `.appended` selector is on the `a` element?

Comment: This was it, mistake on my part there, but it's strange because I think I originally added the `a` to begin with because it wasn't working with just `.appended`

Answer (score 0):

If `$("a .appended")` doesn't return a result the loop won't execute